# Cloud search solution for a large user base with libraries of shared content

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, full-text-search, amazon-cloudsearch

I am looking for a cloud search solution, preferably AWS based (so Elasticsearch or CloudSearch), for a service that maintains a catalog of items and each user can have a subset of these items in their library.

The user should be able to search only their own library. They do not have access to the entire catalog of items.

The solution should be able to support around 20,000 unique items with metadata, and a few million users, each with their own library containing on average 10,000 of those items.

What would be a reasonable configuration to support this? Would either Elasticsearch or CloudSearch meet these requirements?

EDIT:

I am mostly concerned with how to index this in a way that users can search only their own libraries efficiently without adding over a billion records. One thought is using Elasticsearch parent-child relationships between users and the items in their library. The parent would be the user document and the children would be the item documents in their library.

Would this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after further research I have come to the conclusion that this is not something well supported by either CloudSearch or Elasticsearch.

One option I explored is having the library items as children of a user item in Elasticsearch. Unfortunately this doesn't work as children can't have more than one parent. What I was hoping for was many-to-many mappings support, which neither search engine supports.

Adding the userID as an index is also problematic. Because each user would have mostly the same items in their library, indexing on the userID would cause the document size to increase to the tens of billions (1 millions users * 10,000 library items).

In the end I have decided to do an application-side join. I will search the entire catalog and return the results to the service, which will then calculate the intersection of the customer's library and the search results from the entire catalog.

Answer (score 1):

I think either one will handle the the number of items. When determining the size of the search cluster you should also consider the number of requests per second.

Either engine will support it and deliver fast relevant results. Elasticsearch is powered by Apache Lucene, while Cloudsearch based on Solr (which in turn in powered by Lucene!)

I think the consideration then ultimately comes down to a question of maintenance. From what I've gathered [here](http://optimalbi.com/blog/2016/02/16/aws-elasticsearch-vs-aws-cloudsearch/), [here](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/faqs/), and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/faqs/), Cloudsearch is a bit easier because scaling is automatic. I assume that this feature or service will not be serving millions of users from day one so I suggest starting small and scale as needed, as you grow. Cloudsearch makes that easier. Elasticsearch involves more manual intervention.

To limit a user to searching their own libraries I would write a backend service  that handles authentication/authorization before proxying searches to Cloudsearch. You would include a user's unique ID as an indexed field in the search engine records, and search requests would include the user ID.

That backend service could be built in any number of ways but I would recommend looking at API Gateway + Lambda.

Comment: Wouldn't adding the user ID as an indexed field result in a significant increase in the number of items (documents) in the search? For instance, if each user has 10,000 items in their library, we would have 10,000 times 1 million users, which is 10 billion. Those 10 billion items would mostly be the same 10,000 items, but with different values for the user IDs field.